# iis idle timeout and long running request on wcf service

Tags: wcf, iis

I have to implement long running process which is starts via request to the wcf method (not start proces when application start)
I now that this is wrong solution, better will be windows serwis or something else for long running process, but for my situation it is impossible. I have to use wcf servis hosted on IIS.
I read about appdomain recycled and I can't figure out thing about Idle Timeout - appdomain restart if request run over 20 minutes. I know that this issue appears when is started background task in application start.

So will be my appdomain kill when (idle timeout is setup 20 minutes).
it is start one long running request, and after that will be not another request.

When process is started in application start IIS nothing knows about this task and this is for me clear that in this situation appdomain is closed

Does after 20 minutes IIS kill appdomain, besides that eier request still running ? I am confused, because IIS know about still running request and mayby does not do this.

What is true ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IIS will kill the process because it works on a rolling horizon of requests, not what is running.  A way around this might be to have the web service request itself while it is running to continually ping the server to let it know that it is still running.  But on the whole, IIS will kill its processes when no requests are coming in.

Taken directly from MSDN: The worker process shuts down after it finishes processing its existing requests, or after a configured time-out, whichever comes first.

In your case, if your process is longer than the timeout, your process will never finish.